# How to replace string by other strings if the source string contain special characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

In order to clean some string, I have to remove some substring that contains some special UTF-8 characters.

example:

```
source = "Skoda"
to_be_clean = "Škoda Rapid"
```

I need to replace from `to_be_clean` the string `source` by nothing.
Obviously, the `to_be_clean` string contains some special character. Is there a way to do this task simply.
Here is how I am doing it today.

```
output = to_be_clean.replace(source + ' ', '')
```

I was thinking about a regular expression but I need to list all the possible characters.

Comment: It's *really* not clear what you want. Are you hoping to find a way to make `"Škoda"` equal to `"Skoda"` so that you can then remove it? There are many questions about removing accents from Unicode; have you googled those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html)** module should solve your problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodedata
to_be_clean = u"Škoda Rapid"

print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', to_be_clean).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
```

**Output:**

```
Skoda Rapid
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I was actually not aware of unicodedata module. Thanks